# Call controller's action from CLI

Tags: php, symfony

I want to call a controller's action from the command line - how can I do this?

I know there is the whole console component built in, but my application is just a big API, and I don't see a point in separating http and cli requests to different folders. I created the division inside controllers and I want to keep the whole controller code in one place:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    protected function setPermissions()
    {
        $this -> permissions = array(
            'indexAction' => array('authentication' => 1, 'requestType' => array('http', 'cli'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request) : JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse(array('aaa'));
    }

}
```

How can I call, let's say, `DefaultController :: indexAction` from this example from the command line?

Comment: Implement a command which does so?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use command, and your app is one big API, call it the same way as you call from other api clients (by url):

```
 wget http://yourdomain.com/route_path/to_controller/action -O /dev/null
```